# Create embedded instances dynamically during navigation

Tags: groovy

I am really digging groovy's ability to navigate hierarchies of objects elegantly using the dot notation.

One question I have, is there a way to create embedded objects elegantly as well during navigation. For instance, given the following classes:

```
  class Bar {
      int a
  }
  class Foo {
      Bar b
  }
```

I want to be able to do this:

```
  Foo f = new Foo()
  f.b.a = 4
```

Currently, I have to do:

```
  Foo f = new Foo()
  f.b = new Bar()
  f.b.a = 4
```

Note that I need f.b to be null unless it has been set via navigation or otherwise. So blindly instantiating b = new Bar() within the class Foo does not meet the needs of the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You may use null safe operator `?.` Or override a getter for `b` in `Foo` and if it's null set new instance of `b` in `Foo` and return it.

It would be:

```
class Foo {
   Bar b

   Bar getB() {
    if(b == null) 
       this.@b = new Bar()
    b
   }
}
```

Comment: Can't you simplify `this.@b = new Bar()` to `b = new Bar()`?

Comment: Not sure, when getter is overridden.

Comment: "Not sure, when getter is overridden." - No getters are overridden in your code example.

Comment: Ok, will check that on tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize the entire hierarchy in a single line, like so:

```
Foo f = new Foo(b: new Bar(a: 4))
```

Comment: The original question includes "Note that I need f.b to be null unless it has been set via navigation or otherwise.".  It isn't clear what "otherwise" might mean there but I think the wants the thing to be null until/unless it is accessed.  I read it like he just wanted it lazily initialized, but not sure.

Comment: "thanks for the clarification " - Don't take my comment as a clarification. It may be the opposite of clarification. I may have muddied the question even further.  I was just expressing how I read the question.  I may be wrong.